# grub emulate vendor power-on keys with custom controller

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I want to add two buttons to my pc, one should boot windows and another one should boot ubuntu. I read about GRUB vendor power-on keys, but i dont understand how i can add custom buttons here. Should i use simple controller aka arduino to somehow communicate with grub or there is another way to do it ?